# After submitting a form to its self I get a blank page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form that submits to itself and when I submit I get a header and the background but no content on the page, nothing below title in the html. It doesnt write to my database either, no errors, and the styles are there.

I think it has to do with my mysql connection.

I've uploaded everything here https://www.yousendit.com/download/bHlCVWRuTkFTRTUzZUE9PQ

This is for my project as I learn php and mysql and this is a wall I cant get past. Please help!

Comment: Please paste the relevant code here - external download links are generally frowned upon here on SO. Thanks!

Comment: Usually if it displays a blank white page that means PHP encountered some sort of fatal error and the error reporting level said not to output anything.

Comment: Its not white, its just got my header and background styles

Comment: I am not sure where I went wrong, so I include a dl link to all of it.

Comment: How is that "nothing" then? :|

Comment: I did these things: changed <? (was written twice in quoteit-functions.php) with <?PHP in quoteit-functions.php and quoteit-post.php php script was shown in the browser. Then uncommented //global $db; because throwed non declared error in quoteit-post.php Also I did not find where $database variable is declared. I cannot proceed anymore cause I need the db schema. After these changes the page loads the same as before clickin, does not appear blank

Comment: Hmm I made the changes you wrote but it does not fix my issue. I even changed it to my database name 'quoteit' and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php file you have:

```
require_once "quoteit-functions.php";
require_once "quoteit-post.php";
```

and than you have in quoteit-post.php file:

```
require_once "quoteit-functions.php";
```

remove that line because that file is automatic included in that file, instance is used from index.php file.

Comment: I have it so in case I want to use this else where it has the functions it needs. Also, I did this and it does not solve my issue. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Can you remove this to lines from index.php file and add print_r($_POST); and than step by step what is wrong, you can always do after mysql_query: print mysql_error();

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution via my teacher late last night:

The main problem that you don't see anything displayed was because you close the connection in quoteit-post.php - and that's before you attempt to reuse "$db" to display and do the count. I moved it out to index.php.